# Does the iAd App Network shutdown mean my app will no longer display ads?

Tags: developer-program

I'm very unclear about the iAd shutdown announcement. To clarify, I have an app that displays ads. Is the announcement that:

- iAds is shutting down entirely and I need to find another third party ad provider?
- something else about which I'm unclear?

I'm confused because of statements like this on engadget : http://www.engadget.com/2016/01/15/apple-iad-shutdown-june-30th/

> the iAd program as a whole is not shutting down. What is happening, is that the similarly-named iAd App Network, which allows developers to advertise their own apps through iAds, is going away

Comment: This has always been very confusing to me. The Apple communications were never very clear (iAd vs. iPad app network for example) and the Engadget article was just plain wrong. I believed iAd was staying around like Engadget said until my revenue suddenly dried up. I have since moved to AdMob. AdMob ads don't look as good as iAd and the ad content can be sketchy (I got one about mail order brides when testing) but at least it's a revenue stream.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you need to move to a different provider.  With `iAds` shutting down, and assuming you don't have any other third-party provider, such as `AdMob`, serving you ads, your app will not display any ads after the shutdown on **June 30**.

The `iAd` shutdown was announced almost a year ago, giving developers ample time to find other providers and other ways to serve ads.

Comment: I've edited the question a bit. Given the edit, are you sure this answer is correct?

Comment: Yes.  According to [Apple](https://developer.apple.com/support/iad/): "Starting July 1, 2016, iAd will no longer be available for developers to earn revenue by running ads sold by iAd or promote their apps on the iAd App Network."  That link from Engadget is from January, look at the link from Apple instead.